# MPRemoteCommandCenter - distinguish between Lock Screen and Remote Control

Tags: ios, swift

When I receive commands from MPRemoteCommandCenter, e.g. "nextTrackCommand", is there a way in the handler to tell if the command/action was done by the user while using the lock screen or the remote control? I looked at MPRemoteCommandEvent that is passed into the handler but it has no such property.

Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: any luck ? i have same question !!

Comment: No, unfortunately not, still looking for a solution...